# Is there a graphical pager with syntax highlighting?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, syntax-highlighting

Is there a graphical application in the repositories which has keyboard controls like the command-line application "less" and also has syntax highlighting?

I would like it to have arrow keys that scroll the page instead of the cursor, and so there is no need for line wrapping I would like it to scroll the page sideways too.

Comment: Have you tried vim?

Answer (score 1):

I think the program that would be ideal for you is [geany](http://www.geany.org/), which is in the repositories, and is both a text-editor and an IDE (integrated development environment). It has many plugins and support for syntax highlighting for programming languages such as python, java, javascript, etc. The program and its plugins can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins
```

In the screenshot, you can see the useful vertical and horizontal scrollbars. If you go to edit > preferences > keybindings there are a massive number of options, and, according to the [FAQ](http://www.geany.org/Documentation/FAQ), `geany` uses standard GTK+ keybindings. Virtually every action in the editor can be assigned to a key, so I think you will be able to set it up as you wish.

In the screenshot below, I have opened a python script (originally from [this site](http://www.tech-juice.org/2012/05/20/how-to-play-ustream-channels-in-vlc/)) in which I am trying to fix a problem in the way it parses ustream urls. As you can see, both syntax highlighting and some code suggestion/completion is built into the program:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i really really really like geany, however it doesnt really provide the kind of answer you're looking for. iSeth's suggestion is close to the best in my opinion, but doesnt really tell you how to use it. you may have already figured it out, but like most applications, vim accepts in put from STDIN, so you can pipe supported source files to it. I created an alias like this and use it when i need it from a command line, like the scripts that generate XML output for the openbox pipe menus for example.

```
alias vsh="vim -"
```